# how to login to user in python fabric

Tags: python, shell, fabric

I am using Python Fabric. Here is my fabfile.

```
 env.user='XXX'
 env.password='XXX'
 env.key_filename='/key/path'
 env.hosts=[<ip>]

    def install():
    run('ifconfig')
    run('su - hduser')
    run('ls')
    run('sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm')
```

When I run the above fabfile it login to my node and runs 'ifconfig' then i am login into the user hduser and i want to execute all my future command in /home/hduser. But it is executing the commands in root. How can i fix this ? Also if it is asking the password. How can i pass the password in script?

Thanks
Navaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Off, every run command is a separate connection to the computer. This means that after you run the

```
su - hduser
```

the next command will run as if that was never issued.

To run nested commands you need to use

```
with settings(user='hduser',password='Passw0rd1'):
    run('ls')
```

will run the 'ls' command as the hduser and in the hduser home directory and with supply the password.

To run commands in a directory you can also use

```
with cd('/path/to/dir'):
    run ('command in path')
```

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html